# Google Data Studio - Creating your own visualization - config.json problem

Tags: google-visualization, looker-studio

My problem is the index.json

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "concepts",
      "label": "Fields",
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": "dim",
          "label": "label, quadrant, ring, link, active, moved",
          "type": "DIMENSION",
          "options": {
            "min": 6,
            "max": 6
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "style": [

    ...here is unrelated code...

    {
      "id": "offsets",
      "label": "Legend-Offset in pixel",
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": "offset_0",
          "label": "Offset_0 (-500 to 500)",
          "type": "INTERVAL"
        },
        {
          "id": "offset_1",
          "label": "Offset_1 (-500 to 500)",
          "type": "INTERVAL"
        },
        {
          "id": "offset_2",
          "label": "Offset_2 (-500 to 500)",
          "type": "INTERVAL"
        },
        {
          "id": "offset_3",
          "label": "Offset_3 (-500 to 500)",
          "type": "INTERVAL"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In the [config reference](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/config-reference#style_element_options) it's said, that an **interval** needs to have this form:

- INTERVAL Renders an interval selector. Values are integers.  NUMBER  NUMBER  0

And should have an options object.

This means the elements of style **should** look like that:

```
{
          "id": "offset_3",
          "label": "Offset_3 (-500 to 500)",
          "type": "INTERVAL", 
          "defaultValue": 0,
          "options": {
             "min": -500,
             "max": 500
          }
}
```

And that is how the dscc-scripts validation wants it to look like:

```
{
      "id": "offset_3",
      "label": "Offset_3 (-500 to 500)",
      "defaultValue": "0",
      "type": "TEXTINPUT"
}
```

Sadly doing the "should be" blows up the dscc-scripts, with errors telling me, that there **should be no** options and that defaultValue needs to be a string.

Well, doing it as seen in the last code snip fixes this problem and I can indeed build and push my code to the google storage bucket, sadly that won't help me at all as now Data Studio (Browser) blows out errors, telling me that "interval" values need to be of type numbers.

Any idea as how to fix that?

Comment: Actually, in documentation it states that intervals uses Template Strings (with back-ticks, as in https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp). I don't know this make any difference, but it worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Sadly it doesn't help me at all, as the back-ticks just allow me to use "" and '' inside a string. But it is still a string. And it being a string is the very problem.

dscc-scripts validate the code before bundling it all up, and thats the problem.
As the validators require strings as type for the style-type **interval** and yet data studio itself (the one that runs in the browser) cries me a river as it requires those intervall values to be of type number....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution than using type: "TEXTFIELD":

Just changed the schemas the dscc-scripts package uses to fit the homepage. (so I changed it from string to number)
I don't really get why they would not do that themselves since they changed types from string to numbers, but nvm that.

Here what I changed in schemas.js (node_modules/@google/dscc-scripts/builds/viz/schemas.js):

(See type under defaultValue...)

```
...
interval: {
        type: 'object',
        additionalProperties: false,
        required: ['id', 'label', 'type'],
        properties: {
            id: { type: 'string' },
            label: { type: 'string' },
            type: {
                type: 'string',
                enum: ['INTERVAL'],
            },
            defaultValue: { type: 'number' },
        },
    },
...
```

#QuestionClosed